# Accessing shared onedrive txt file - 403 forbiden error

Tags: xamarin, onedrive

I want to access shared (for anyone with the link) .txt file from OneDrive. I want do it this way in order to avoid configuring whole this API stuff but, I get **403 forbiden** error.

```
            WebClient web = new WebClient();
            web.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            web.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            System.IO.Stream stream = web.OpenRead(myPathToTxtFile);

            using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string text = reader.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(text);
                }
            }
```

Comment: A "shared" OneDrive url is not to the file itself, but to the OneDrive HTML/JS viewer/wrapper.

Comment: @SushiHangover thank You, but it doesn't tell me much - any ideas for solution? I just need to read only this specific file...

Comment: Consider adding [Microsoft Graph SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation#install-the-microsoft-graph-net-sdk) to your project and using the  `GraphServiceClient` object to read the files asynchronously.